# No Module Found Django while sending mail

Tags: python, django, smtp

When I tried sending mails from my django project, experienced this problem.
I tried these commands:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail("sub", "body", "test@test.com", ["xyz@gmail.com"])
```

All the email settings are properly configured and it is running on other systems, but it is showing this error on my Ubuntu 20.04 django project

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
        exec(code, self.locals)
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/nishi/nishi/campaignmanager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 51, in send_mail
        connection = connection or get_connection(
      File "/home/nishi/nishi/campaignmanager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 34, in get_connection
        klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
      File "/home/nishi/nishi/campaignmanager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
        module = import_module(module_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"django'
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '"django' Is this the actual error code? are you sure there's no typo?

Comment: Try to install Django using built-in pip "python3 -m pip install django"